# .NET pop-up box terminology along with Java

Tags: java, visual-studio

I need to know a couple things.

1. What is the terminology for the pop-up box shown in this [Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/16060e2a55.png)? (Not the text, but the actual box itself) This is with Visual Studios.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/16060e2a55.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/16060e2a55.png)

2. I need to do a project in Java and I heard that Eclipse has this pop-up box, but I cant seem to find it. Does anyone know where this option is? I was hoping maybe finding out the terminology of the box will help me find the option easier.
3. Is there a better IDE for java than Eclipse with this box included?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), it's activated automatically, but can be invoked manually using Ctrl+Space.
2. Yes, Eclipse does have this as well.  Press Ctrl+Space to bring it up (I don't think Eclipse does it manually - it's been a couple of months since I last used Eclispe so I may be wrong).
3. You might want to look into IntelliJ IDEA or Netbeans (the former over the latter).  IMHO, Eclipse is the most powerful and represents best value for money :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: The box shown in the image is indeed part of Intellisense, but Intellisense is a Microsoft trademark. The generic term for the technology is autocompletion or code completion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocompletion

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Mark, you're quite right of course.